# How do I use the Charge Blade weapon effectively?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

The Charge Blade, as you may know, is the new weapon to Monster Hunter series. With its Sword & shield and Axe mode, it's a bit confusing to determine when and how to use which mode. I figured out how charge the Sword and that you can KO with the Axe mode by using the A button attacks.

So, my question is, what are the core mechanics of the weapon and when I should utilize them to get the most out of the weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the general strategy with the charge blade is to never convert energy into phials when it's glowing yellow, only red so you get the most out of each recharge. The gauge will gradually go from no glow to yellow to red as you attack in sword and shield mode. Once that hits red, hold R and press A to convert those into phials. Once you have those, the A attacks in axe mode get a serious boost to both KO ad damage, at the cost of one phial per attack. You generally want to go all out whenever you have three or more phials, and try to recharge in sword mode until you're back up to five. Also, if you realize you're going to miss with the axe mode A charge attack, press R to change the attack into a boost for your shield. That will make your shield as strong as a lance's for as long as the buff is active. Normal attacks in axe mode without phials are very wimpy compared to how much you could be dealing.

tl;dr Charge in Sword mode until red, recharge and mash A in Axe mode until phials are low, rinse and repeat.

Comment: What about elements, does it benefit from them or is raw damage more important?

Comment: I have yet to play the full game, as it isn't out yet here in the states, but I'd assume that, like most heavy weapons, raw damage is more important than the right element, though it still helps. I'd imagine the sword and shield mode could still make decent use of elemental damage though.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. Can always add the thing about elemental vs. raw damage later, or maybe I'll make that into another full question closer to/after the English release.

Comment: Well after playing some time with the charge blade ( charge axe in spanish) i can tell you that the axe mode elemental phial atacks are really strong, they can output a really great elemental damage thanks to the multihit, and if you do an ultra charge atack the damage skyrockets, i was able to nearly 1 shot a kutku in low level exploration